# How to find systems cached and free memory using C#

Tags: c#, caching, memory

I couldnt able to find the cached and free memory of a system using C#.Help me.......[image: How to find cached and free memory]

Comment: Have you ever look at Performance Counters as `\Memory\Cache Bytes`?

Comment: @SonerGönül....Yes I've used that.Its giving Cached memory as 233.44 mb but originally shown in task manager as some 3800 mb....huge difference

Comment: Use System.Management to [read this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394314%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  Download WMI Code Creator and let it generate the code you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `Microsoft.VisualBasic.Devices` assembly reference to your project then you can use following

```
        var Available = new ComputerInfo().AvailablePhysicalMemory;
        var Total = new ComputerInfo().TotalPhysicalMemory;
        var Cheched = Total - Available;
```

**Edit:**

Following code works for me, also note that Available amount includes the Free Amount and also includes *most* of the Cached amount.

```
        ObjectQuery wql = new ObjectQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_OperatingSystem");
        ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(wql);
        ManagementObjectCollection results = searcher.Get();

        //total amount of free physical memory in bytes
        var Available = new ComputerInfo().AvailablePhysicalMemory;
        //total amount of physical memory in bytes
        var Total = new ComputerInfo().TotalPhysicalMemory;

        var PhysicalMemoryInUse = Total - Available;
        Object Free = new object();
        foreach (var result in results)
        {
            //Free amount
            Free = result["FreePhysicalMemory"];
        }


        var Cached = Total - PhysicalMemoryInUse - UInt64.Parse(Free.ToString());

        Console.WriteLine("Available: " + ByteToGb(Available));
        Console.WriteLine("Total: " + ByteToGb(Total));
        Console.WriteLine("PhysicalMemoryInUse: " + ByteToGb(PhysicalMemoryInUse));
        Console.WriteLine("Free: " + ByteToGb(UInt64.Parse( Free.ToString())));
        Console.WriteLine("Cached: " + ByteToGb(Cached));
```

[image]

Comment: Available and Total memory are exactly correct but cached = Total-available seems wrong....because from the above cached not = 7896-4056 which gives 3840........

Comment: Ya...It seems gud in WINDOWS 8 but in WINDOWS 7 free memory calculation is coming as available memory.....

Comment: I see, [this](http://brandonlive.com/2010/02/21/measuring-memory-usage-in-windows-7/) might help you to adjust the code for Windows7

Comment: Nice! would you please provide some details on how you got it to work? If my post answered you question, please consider accepting it.